# selector not worked first time onclick in android

Tags: android, radio-button, selector

I have four radio buttons which are options of question.
I have to apply onclick listener here.
I want if user click on right answer background use first selector and if select wrong answer second selector work and the radio button which have right answer also show its pressed event I have to set selector on run time.
And I have single page for multiple question.problem is selector not worked fine while i click on first time on radio button.and second time it works fine.but with wrong answer how could i call oppressed of right answer radio button.

This is my selector code:-

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/brown"  />
      <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/green"  />
      <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/green"  />
 </selector>
```

code of one radio button but i have four case for four radiobutton like this:-

```
  case R.id.radio0:
            clickSound();
            if (radio0.isChecked()) {
                user_ans = radio0.getText().toString().trim();
                if (correct_answer.equalsIgnoreCase(user_ans)) {

                    radio0.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_selector_brown);
                    ern_score += 1000;
                    score.setText(String.valueOf(ern_score));
                } else {
                    radio0.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_selector_brown);
                }
                ++ctr;
            }
            break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
radio3.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red_selector_gray));
```

use this it will solve your problem